# Array concatenation does not work in bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I am trying to concatenate arrays on Command Line Interface.
example:

```
array1=( a b c )
```

However, echo $array1 prints only the first element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print the complete array, you will have to get all array members:

```sh
array1=( a b c );
echo ${array1[@]}
> a b c
```

More information about bash arrays [here](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays).

Comment: You should almost always use double-quotes (`"${array1[@]}"` instead of just `${array1[@]}`) to prevent weird parsing.